# Couldn't able to access graphql playground from localhost in XM Cloud

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud, experience-edge

I'm encountering a CORS issue when making requests to the Preview GraphQL IDE. Despite setting the sc_apikey in the header, I'm still facing problems. The error message I receive is:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xmc-*********-test.sitecorecloud.io/sitecore/api/graph/edge' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Additionally, I'm getting a 400 (Bad Request) error when making a POST request to `https://xmc-***********-test.sitecorecloud.io/sitecore/api/graph/edge`

Interestingly, I can access the IDE playground directly via URL and successfully make GraphQL queries within the playground. However, I'm unable to replicate this success on my localhost.

I've attempted to use `https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge` and `https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/ide`, but neither of these has resolved the issue.

Currently I'm using NextJS+React with @apollo/client
Any advice or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correctly the URL and the ApiKey parameters to run against the local instance of XM Cloud.

[image: the 3 important things we have to set up are:]

In the image above, the 3 important things we have to set up are:

1. The URL to launch the Playground IDE locally:

   `https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/authoring/graphql/ide/`
2. The local endpoint to reach GraphQL API:

   `https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge`
3. The ApiKey: The ApiKey is the ID value of the Sitecore item of our local XM located in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys/xmcloudpreview`

[image]

It has to match the value of the variable of our `.env` file in the NextJs solution:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Credit: [How to work with GraphQL in your local environment](https://sitecoretek.wordpress.com/2023/08/28/xm-cloud-how-to-work-with-graphql-in-your-local-environment/)

Answer (score 0):

While working with docker, make sure that you have enabled these two settings in your `.env` file.

```
SITECORE_GRAPHQL_ENABLED=true
SITECORE_GRAPHQL_EXPOSEPLAYGROUND=true
```

When you enable these settings, you will be able to access the graphQL playground.

Hope this helps.