Preview GraphQL is not working with XM Cloud
I have made my containers up and Sitecore is accessible on https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/shell/?sc_lang=en I have made the entry in the .env for the following:
SITECORE_GRAPHQL_ENABLED=true
SITECORE_GRAPHQL_EXPOSEPLAYGROUND=true

but still https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/authoring/graphql/ide/ is giving 404.

Please let me know the setting(s) I need to verify to check what is missing.

Have you checked this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36801/couldnt-able-to-access-graphql-playground-from-localhost-in-xm-cloud

Yes I checked it but I am unable to access the IDE.

Did you create ApiKey in System/services? If its container tries restarting your docker!

Yes, it is available. Even I tried to pass the sc_apikey header in the query string as well then it gives the message as "no query found!"

Did you tried restarting your containers? Restarting your docker will make your changes available. Check your license file too.

Have you checked this? https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/set-up-the-graphql-playgrounds-to-test-published-content.html

The documentation is for XM Cloud available on cloud but I want to try locally. So, I have verified the apikey not sure what else is required to make the IDE available for local.

You are using the wrong Url for the preview end point. That Url is for the admin and authoring graphql API.
The preview end point for a locally running docker instance is:
https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/graph/edge/ide

That preview end point is enabled by default, you don't need to change any config. You will need to get your API key and add it to the headers once the playground is loaded.

Superb @Richard Seal. This is what I was finding.

@georgeCarter - You can go through this documentation explaining the same. Thought the question is answered, just sharing so that you can get more details of it.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/set-up-the-graphql-playgrounds-to-test-published-content.html#set-up-the-preview-api-playground
